# How to use the "findBy" method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm pretty new to programming, so please have mercy :)

I have to work on a project with Spring and I currently have some struggles on how to use the findBy Method.

I want to create a folder-system, where you can see every folder other users shared by setting the `private boolean shared = true;`

Next thing I did was to edit the service class of "folder" and I want to write something like this:

```
public List<Folder> getsharedFolder() {
    return folderRepository.findBy___();
}
```

How can I exactly get folders where the boolean "shared" was set to true?

Comment: You need to share the code for the `Folder` class. I assume it has a `shared` property, so maybe `orderRepository.findByShared(Boolean shared)`, but it's hard to tell without the actual code. On the other hand what's orderRepository? shouldn't it be `folderRepository`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to translate that. It is folderRepository, I changed it in the opening post.

The Folder class:
`@Entity
public class Folder{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer FolderID;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String Foldername;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "folder")
    private List<Card> Foldercontent= new ArrayList<>();
    
    private boolean geteilt = false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this method:

```
 List<Folder> findBySharedTrue();
```

On your `FolderRepository` class:

```
public interface FolderRepository extends CrudRepository<Folder, Integer> {
     List<Folder> findBySharedTrue();
}
```

It will use the field `shared` from the entity `Folder` and return only the folders with `shared` field equals to `true`.

Comment: Another thing he can do is `List<Folder> findByShared(Boolean shared)` then he can get either all the shared folders or non shared folders depending on application. Some Databases the boolean value is represented as a short like mysql.

Answer (score 0):

## Using `JPARepository` instead of `CRUDRepository`

## Entity

```
@Entity
public class Folder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer FolderID;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String Foldername;
    private boolean geteilt = false;

    public Integer getFolderID() {
        return FolderID;
    }

    public void setFolderID(Integer folderID) {
        FolderID = folderID;
    }

    public String getFoldername() {
        return Foldername;
    }

    public void setFoldername(String foldername) {
        Foldername = foldername;
    }



    public boolean isGeteilt() {
        return geteilt;
    }

    public void setGeteilt(boolean geteilt) {
        this.geteilt = geteilt;
    }

}
```

## Repository

```
public interface FolderRepository extends JpaRepository<Folder, Integer>{

    List<Folder> findByGeteilt(boolean shared);

}
```

## Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class FolderTest{

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private FolderRepository folderrepo;


    @Test
    public void whenFindByshared() {

        // given

        Folder folder = new Folder();
        folder.setFolderID(1);
        folder.setFoldername("folder1");
        folder.setGeteilt(true);

        Folder folder1 = new Folder();
        folder1.setFolderID(2);
        folder1.setFoldername("folder2");
        folder1.setGeteilt(true);

        Folder folder2 = new Folder();
        folder2.setFolderID(1);
        folder2.setFoldername("folder3");
        folder2.setGeteilt(false);

        folderrepo.saveAndFlush(folder);
        folderrepo.saveAndFlush(folder1);
        folderrepo.saveAndFlush(folder2);

        // when

        List<Folder> sharedFolders =new ArrayList<>();
        sharedFolders = folderrepo.findByGeteilt(true);

        assertThat(sharedFolders.get(0).getFoldername())
          .isEqualTo(folder1.getFoldername());


    }

}
```

## Resultat

[image: test success]

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of the "findBy" method the function will be able to work if you set a boolean as your criterion for search (refer to this website for documentation: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html).

However, you could create an attribute that is the String variation of the boolean value (as in keep a string value for true/false). The findBy method should work fine in that instance.

If you don't wish to add an extra component you could try inheriting the class and then overriding the method (create a superclass) that will also check for the boolean component (maybe extend the functionality?). However, I'm not sure how you would implement that and it's more an abstract idea than a real suggestion